# cakephp 3 increment record

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0

I try to increment a table record from my controller but it fails,i want to create an add to basket method which will insert a new product or update the quantity of an existing one.
Also i would like to know if there is any book or tutorial(except the tutorial from the cakephp site) which explains in detail cakephp.
I am a beginner to cakephp and seems very confusing,any help is welcome and appreciated.

Controller

My code:

```
>  function add($id = null,$name = null){
>        
>        $addCart = $this->Cart->newEntity();
> 
>        if($this->request->is('Get')){
>           
>           $data1 = $this->Cart->exists(['productId' => $id]);
>         
>         //if product doesn't exist in table then add it
>           if(!$data1){ 
>             $addCart = $this->Cart->patchEntity($addCart,[
>                                                 'productId' => $id,
>                                                 'name' => $name,
>                                                 'productQty' => 1]
>                                                 );
>             if($this->Cart->save($addCart)){
>               $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));
>               return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users','action' => 'index']);
>             }else{
>               $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
>             }
> 
>           }else{ //if product already exists in table then update quantity
>             $updateQty = $this->Cart->patchEntity($addCart, [
>                                                ['productQty' => 'productQty+1'],
>                                                'conditions' => ['productId' => $id] //update quantity where the product id matches
>                                                ]);
>            if($this->Cart->save($updateQty)){
>               $this->Flash->success(__('The product already exists.Quantity updated'));
>               return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'users','action' => 'index']);
>            }else{
>               $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be updated. Please, try again.'));
>            }
>           }//end inner if
> 
>        }//end if
>         }//end function
```

VIEW

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
  <?= $this->Html->link('Add Product',['controller' => 'Cart', 'action' => 'add',2,'gpu'])
      //$this->Html->link('Add Product',['controller' => 'Cart', 'action' => 'index'])
  ?>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the current value, incrementing on PHP level and updating the table is prone to race conditions, instead, use an expression to add a raw SQL snippet that increments the column value at DB level

```
$query = $this->Cart->query();
$result = $query
    ->update()
    ->set(
        $query->newExpr('productQty = productQty + 1')
    )
    ->where([
        'productId' => $id
    ])
    ->execute();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Updating Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#updating-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**

Comment: Ok thank you. works without $query->newExpr. set([('productQty = productQty + 1')])